# Ajax PHP - Result is only echoed if DOM Explorer is Open (Edge)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I have a page that calls a PHP script every 4 seconds with Ajax. The PHP script echoes out some text which is then put in a div on the page. (The PHP script does connect to a MySQL server, could that be the reason for my problems below?)

Here's the strange part. The first time the PHP script is called, it echoes all the text fine. However after 4 seconds, when Ajax calls the PHP script again, the page becomes blank. To make things even more strange, when I right-click View Source on MS Edge, all of the page content loads in, and then if I close the Source Code, after 4 seconds it disappears again.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

My JS file with Ajax:

```
function updateCandles(){
    var candleIndexStart = $('#candle-index-start').text();
    var candleSort = $('#candle-sort').text();
    var resultArray = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'php/display_candles.php',
        data: {
            'sort': candleSort,
            'candle-start': candleIndexStart
        },
        async: false
    }).responseText.split("h8ktncuidabciafvabc7932hcueqbc73gd8713gdy713gd6831df8136fd13d");
    $('.candles').html(resultArray[0]);
    $('#candle-counter').html(resultArray[1]);
    setTimeout(updateCandles, 4000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    updateCandles();
});
```

My PHP Script:

```
<?php

session_start();

function timeAgo($time_ago)
{
    $time_ago = strtotime($time_ago);
    $cur_time   = time();
    $time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $time_ago;
    $seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
    $minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
    $hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
    $days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
    $weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
    $months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
    $years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );
    // Seconds
    if($seconds <= 60){
        return "just now";
    }
    //Minutes
    else if($minutes <=60){
        if($minutes==1){
            return "one minute ago";
        }
        else{
            return "$minutes minutes ago";
        }
    }
    //Hours
    else if($hours <=24){
        if($hours==1){
            return "an hour ago";
        }else{
            return "$hours hrs ago";
        }
    }
    //Days
    else if($days <= 7){
        if($days==1){
            return "yesterday";
        }else{
            return "$days days ago";
        }
    }
    //Weeks
    else if($weeks <= 4.3){
        if($weeks==1){
            return "a week ago";
        }else{
            return "$weeks weeks ago";
        }
    }
    //Months
    else if($months <=12){
        if($months==1){
            return "a month ago";
        }else{
            return "$months months ago";
        }
    }
    //Years
    else{
        if($years==1){
            return "one year ago";
        }else{
            return "$years years ago";
        }
    }
}

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "pass", "db");

if(!$connection) {
    echo "Error";
}

if($_GET['teacher'] == 'yes'){
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM candles WHERE approved=0 ORDER BY date desc LIMIT " . $_GET['candle-start'] . ",20");
} else {
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM candles WHERE approved=1 ORDER BY date " . $_GET['sort'] . " LIMIT " . $_GET['candle-start'] . ",20");
}

if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    $counter = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $counter = $counter + 1;
        if($counter % 2 == 1){
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class='candle-row'>";
        }
        if($row["approved"] == 1 and $_GET['teacher'] == 'yes') {
            continue;
        }
        echo "<div class='candle'><div class='candle-icon'>";
        echo '<span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-' . $row["candle_icon_type"] . ' fa-stack-1x" style="color: ' . $row["colour"] . '"></i></span></div>';
        echo '<div style="display:table;height:100%;"><div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;"><div>';
        echo "<h3><a href='candle.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'>For " . ucwords($row["title"]) . "</a></h3>";
        echo "<br>";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $row['user_id'] . " LIMIT 1");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
                if($row["anonymous"] == 1 and $_SESSION["user_group"] == '1'){
                    echo "<h4><a href='candle.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'>Shared by an Anonymous User<br>";
                } else {
                    echo "<h4><a href='candle.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'>Shared by " . $row1["username"] . "<br>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "<h4><a href='candle.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'>Shared by Unknown<br>";
        }
        echo "Shared " . ucwords(timeAgo($row["date"])) . "<br>" . $row['fuel'] . " Fuel</a></h4></div></div></div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}

echo "h8ktncuidabciafvabc7932hcueqbc73gd8713gdy713gd6831df8136fd13d";

if($_GET['teacher']) {
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id FROM candles WHERE approved=0");
} else {
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id FROM candles WHERE approved=1");
}

if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) == 0){
    echo '0 Candles';
} elseif(mysqli_num_rows($result1) == 1){
    echo '1 Candle';
} else {
    echo mysqli_num_rows($result1) . ' Candles';
}

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot, edited now.

Answer (score 0):

yes, `EDGE` does seem to miss the `console` object when you don't have it opened (the DOM Explorer as you called it). when your `console` is closed, it doesn't "exist", so `EDGE` throws an error which you can't see because your `console` is closed.

(*sounds weird to you? welcome to `Microsoft` created logic*)!

I guess you are using the `console.log()` method in you code. so either you remove your `console.log()` calls or you put this workaround to the top of your javascript:

```
if (!window.console) window.console = {};
if (!window.console.log) window.console.log = function () { };
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what parts of my code I should put inside the function in the code you provided. I have updated my question with my current code.

Comment: @Th3Gam3rz just put it the first javascript-line. is this really all the code you are using? because you got no `console` in the code you are providing.

Comment: Yes, this is the code. I added the two lines you provided to the beginning of the JS file and no different.

Comment: I knew old versions of IE had this problem, I can't believe it still exists in IE.

Comment: @Th3Gam3rz ok, then nevermind. it sounded like a problem i have had with IE.